# SVG - trigonometric function to get a Point in dependence on a different angle

Tags: javascript, svg

i'm working with the vivagraph library and i try to get a point depend on the angle of two nodes.

But i don't know how i get this point. 
I get the angle between the two nodes, but do not know how I calculate the point.

I work with the example from the programmer and I've uploaded my extensions here

http://jsbin.com/umepoq/3/

I tried to make clearer, in a sketch
http://imageshack.us/a/img844/3904/stackoverflowfrage.png

Maybe someone can give me a hint. :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've looked at your image, and the jsbin, and I still can't tell what your question means.

Comment: Hi Alnitak, i want to place for example a circle next to man with the blue background and when i drag the b/w man and pull him over the screen the circle should be in the same angle. sorry my english is not so good, i think i make a new image to explain that further.

Comment: Second try :-) http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3171/v3yehzgg_png.htm

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the black and white picture is point A, the blue background picture remains fixed and is point B and the black dot is point C.  If I understand you correctly you want the angle ABC to remain constant while point A is moved.

If the three parts of your picture are all part of the same group when you rotate the group by an angle then all parts within that group will be rotated by the same angle.  This should preserve the angle ABC.